# jQuery going back 2 parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey all I am trying to get to the following tag:

```
<tr class="grid-layout-row">
```

in this HTML:

```
<tr class="grid-layout-row">
    <td role="presentation" class="grid-layout-row-leader">
        <div class="grid-layout-row-leader-spacer"></div>
    </td>
    <td role="presentation" class="grid-layout-cell  F_Form1-P_NewPage-F_DatePosted_cell">
            ....... lots of code here
    </td>
</tr>
```

From starting at this tag:

```
<td role="presentation" class="grid-layout-row-leader">
    <div class="grid-layout-row-leader-spacer"></div>
</td>
```

I've tried:

```
var curr = $('td[class*=-F_DatePosted_cell').parent().prev();
```

But that seems to pick up the tag before:

```
<tag here that it gets>
<tr class="grid-layout-row">
```

What would I be missing?

Comment: all you want is `parent()` I think...although the way you've asked is a bit confusing

Comment: Use `$(...).parent().parent()`

Comment: The parent of a `<td>` tag is the `<tr>` tag.  I'm not sure why you'd need to traverse any further than just `.parent()`.

Comment: Where's an element with the class containing `F_CheckBox2_cell`?

Comment: `closest` will be best option here. `$(this).closest('.grid-layout-row')`

Comment: [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) gets the element's previous sibling (not parent).

Comment: is this a problem in an event handler? How are you using this? If it's n event handler problem ... selector needs to be relative to target

Comment: @j08691 Fix that in the OP.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `parent` because structures change over time and best practice is to not rely on the precise position in DOM. Use `closest` to travel up to first parent with matching selector, like so:

```
$(".grid-layout-row-leader-spacer").closest(".grid-layout-row");
```

Comment: valid html structure of a table can't change...td can only have `tr` as parent.

Comment: You are correct, but layout tables may be nested, and the origin element is *not* `td`, it is a `div`. Plus at some point in time it may stop becoming a `table` and use something else like `div` instead; my answer reflects best practices for enterprise software.

Comment: have been thinking that ...OP left some critical parts of this out

Comment: hence my solution that works for many situations when you want to ascend up to first parent found with matching selector

Answer (score -2):

You should use parents().

```
var curr = $('td[class*=-F_CheckBox2_cell').parents('.grid-layout-row');
```

Comment: huh...parent of a tr will be tbody. thead, tfoot or table

Comment: Yes I edited my answer after I realized that. I answered based on wanting to go back 2 parents. parent().parent() rather than thoroughly reading his html :(

Comment: This is not recommended because `parents` may return multiple results. (hint is in the plural "s")